# Paperclip: Block original file from being uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-s3

I have a video model which currently accepts a video url instead of a multipart video file.

The video is uploaded through application onto S3 bucket.

Now over here I want to upload just the style images and processor video(attached with timestamp values on each frame).

But still the original video is being uploaded to the server from the url. I have already uploaded the video to S3 and do not want to repeat the process through paperclip.

Any way to restrict the original video from being uploaded

***Video.rb***

```
has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    timestamped: { processors: %i[ timestamper ] },
    small: ['640x', :jpeg],
    medium: ['750x', :jpeg],
    large: ['1242x', :jpeg]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `original` type and use it as `large`. For example:

```
has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    timestamped: { processors: %i[ timestamper ] },
    original: ['1242x', :jpeg],
    medium: ['750x', :jpeg],
    small: ['640x', :jpeg]
}
```

be careful that the original is used as a "base" for the other styles.

Another solution is to unlink the file after the process but this means that the file is first uploaded anyway:

```
after_save :reprocess_video

private

def reprocess_video
    File.unlink(video.path)
end
```

Comment: Actually that is the main concern. I do not want any other style except original which I have already uploaded directly to S3. But while uploading the url through paperclip, the original(again) comes along.

Comment: So the first solution of my answer should fit your need.

Comment: I tried your first solution but it is still uploading a jpeg file in the original folder. I can later delete it but that will be a concern since it will increase the PUT operation for S3 and that is costly with respect to a large application.